# Can I share common link-references for links in many, separated typedoc comments?

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I have a situation like this:

```
/**
 * A Class.
 *
 * [Google] and [Wikipedia] enter a bar.
 *
 * [Google]: https://www.google.com
 * [Wikipedia]: https://en.wikipedia.org
 */
class MyClass {
  // ...
}


/**
 * Another class.
 *
 * I want to know more about [Google] and [Wikipedia].
 *
 * [Google]: https://www.google.com
 * [Wikipedia]: https://en.wikipedia.org
 */
class AnotherClass {
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, it would be nice to have a unique source for my "*bibliography*" instead of repeating the same links in each typedoc. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

On top of your document, you can add external links as follows in the right format so you don't need to repetitively add the link again and again.

```
 /**
    * @author  Daniele Repici
    * @version 1.0
    * @since   2019/09/18
    * [FormArray]: <a href="https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup</a>
    * [FormArray]: <a href="https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray</a>
    */
```

> Don't use {@link ...} or {@linkplain ...} because these are for links to the javadocs of other classes and methods.

Comment: According to its [documentation](https://typedoc.org/guides/doccomments/#markdown), Typescript uses the [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked#marked) markdown parser, which 
[does not envisage](https://marked.js.org/demo/) the anchor element for the link. In fact, your solution does not seem to work.
Problem is: it doesn't work with plain URLs either.